# Efficiency of MongoDB $in operator on indexed fields

Tags: mongodb, groovy

What's the difference in performance of MongoDB if `$in` operator is used for a list of values against the querying for each value individually and vice versa.

E.g. if I have a list of some values like `values = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]` then which way of querying would be better ?

option a)

```
find({value: [$in: values]})
```

option b)

```
values.each { val ->
    find({value: val})
}
```

Comment: The first things that comes to mind before even thinking about time cost of the queries is the network noise and the amount of cursors being opened in option b compared to a

Comment: ya in the second approach n number of cursors will be opened but i guess mongodb is efficient enough in managing them

Comment: And **Noise** meaning pulling things over the network connection as opposed to running the operations on the server. Think of query operators in a similar way to **extra work** you want done using SQL rather than iterating results in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, `$in` is very fast unless the array is huge (say a couple of thousand ids from experience, your mileage may vary).

Like @Sammaye already pointed out, there is considerable overhead for each query (network/thread synchronization, serialization of the actual BSON message, network latency, cursor management, etc.) so I'd bet `$in` will be faster almost all cases that are relevant in practice. If the array gets huge, it might be better to perform a few larger `in` queries instead of one huge `in` query though.